# Excel Function Formula

Tags: excel

```
QTY I.D     DN  LENGTH  TOTAL
22  PIPE    300 6.000   132.000
11  PIPE    300 6.000   66.000
79  PIPE    300 6.000   474.000
114 PIPE    300 6.000   684.000
5   PIPE    400 6.000   30.000
6   COUPLER 500 6.000   36.000
```

Given sample above, what is the function to use in excel to quantify the sum of length for Specific Pipe DN?

Comment: question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D7,B2:B7,"PIPE",C2:C7,H2)
```

where `Cell H2` will have the value for DN.

See image for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

=SUMIFS(E2:E7,B2:B7,H1,C2:C7,H2)
where H1 is ID (in our case PIPE)
and H2 is DN (in our case 300)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43SON.png)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the first column is "A", try `SUMIF("C2:C7","=300","D2:D7")`. This will give you the total length of pipes with DN=300.

Comment: What if a coupler has a DN of 300? Why are your ranges in quotes?

Comment: I used it as an example of the function SUMIF. If you check the documentation, you will understand how this function works. You can add some additional logic to test the value of column "B".

Comment: Actually, no you cannot. The [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) only takes a single criteria; the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) takes multiple criteria and has very different syntax and neither uses quoted cell ranges.

Comment: You are right about SUMIF, but there are many ways to do it. Still, I agree that SUMIFS is a better solution.